# Assessing covariate balance for a propensity score model with interactions

Tags: r, stata, propensity-scores

I am interested in determining the covariate balance of a PS model with high-order interaction terms. How can assess this? I have explored the use of standardized differences but I am running into problems because of the interaction terms in the model.

Comment: Have you tried the package [MatchIt](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/index.html) with its [balance assessment](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/assessing-balance.html) functionality?

Comment: Curious what made PS a good choice for your problem.

Comment: @FrankHarrell My study is observational and I have many confounders to adjust for. Thus, to avoid the finite sample bias problem, Ps was a good choice because of my small sample

Comment: Sounds good.  You might consider interacting the logit of propensity score with selected individual predictors.

Answer (score 2):

The form of the propensity score model has nothing to do with how you should assess balance. You should always assess balance on as many terms as possible, including interactions and other features of the covariate distribution. Different software make this easier or harder. If you are using `cobalt` to assess balance, you can just set `int = TRUE` in the call to `bal.tab()` to get standardized mean differences on all pairwise interactions. If you are using `MatchIt`, you can do the same in a call to `summary()`. If you want to test balance on specific interactions or higher-order terms, you can manually add them using the `addl` arguments to both functions.

There are some balance statistics that attempt to assess balance in the full joint covariate distributions (i.e., all possible interactions), like the L1 statistic and energy distance. These are good for comparing matching specifications but not necessarily for deciding whether a sample is "balanced" or not.

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer